# QML Swipeview Attached Properties

Tags: qt, qml

In the QML [SwipeView documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html#index-attached-prop), it lists some attached properties for SwipeView children. For example

> SwipeView.index : int
>
> This attached property holds the index of each child item in the SwipeView.
>
> It is attached to each child item of the SwipeView.

From a SwipeView child, how do I access these properties? I have noticed the normal SwipeView properties do not reference `SwipeView.` for example [`vertical`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html#vertical-prop)

Ultimately I want to change SwipeView's current item by providing it the child's attached index property, for example

```
SwipeView {
    id: view

    currentIndex: aBool ? firstPage.index : secondPage.index
    anchors.fill: parent

    Item {
        id: firstPage
    }
    Item {
        id: secondPage
    }
    Item {
        id: thirdPage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the attached properties from a SwipeView child, need to provide `SwipeView.` before the attached proptery.

Therefore my example above would be

```
SwipeView {
    id: view

    currentIndex: aBool ? firstPage.SwipeView.index : secondPage.SwipeView.index
    anchors.fill: parent

    Item {
        id: firstPage
    }
    Item {
        id: secondPage
    }
    Item {
        id: thirdPage
    }
}
```